# Filter GAE Key Field with Substring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind named Posts and the key is postId.

The postId format is : YYMMDDXXX. Where XXX is 3 digits sequence number.

For example : 150703001, 150704001, 150704002

How do I get the sequence number from my entities in datastore? I want to convert this SQL `Select nvl(max(substring(postId, 7, 3)), 0) from posts where substring(postId, 1, 6) = '150704'` to Objectivy filter.

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain in more user-centric terms what you are trying to do? This is a poorly chosen natural key used where a synthetic key is appropriate. If you want to order posts by date, add an indexed date field.

Comment: @stickfigure Hi, what I'm trying to do is just to make a primary key. Do you have any other way to make an auto-generated primary key?

Comment: Just leave the `@Id Long id` null. It will be populated on save with an allocated unique id. Even smarter is to pre-allocate ids on construction using the `ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()` method so that you never have objects without an id. This is all stuff at the "beginning of the manual" so-to-speak; you will waste a lot less time if you at least skim the docs for Objectify and GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to re-design your Kinds/Entities into a different structure to accomplish this. The datastore can not search by substring.

A possible approach could be this layout :

```
@Entity
class PostGroup {

 @Id
 String id; // this is will hold the formatted date YYMMDD

}

@Entity 
class Post {

  @Id
  Long id; // auto generated ID

  @Index
  Long sequence; //  the sequence number

  @Parent
  Key<PostGroup> group;

}
```

Now you can set the `PostGroup` has the **ancestor** for your Objectify query, `sort by Post.sequence desc limit 1` to find the latest post.

```
String yymmdd = "150704";
Key<PostGroup> postGroupKey = Key.create(PostGroup.class, yymmdd);
Query<Post> query = ofy().type(Post.class).ancestor(postGroupKey).order("-sequence");
Post latestPost = query.first().now();
```

Note: you don't have to actually persist the `PostGroup`s to use them as ancestors.

Comment: Hi @koma, thanks for your answer. Could you give me the example code for getting the latest Post, please? Sorry, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: This won't actually work. `id` is not an indexed field; it's part of the key, and therefore can't be `order`ed on (you could order on `__key__` but that has different behavior). Also, autogenerated ids do not increase monotonically (they are scattered), so even if you could filter/order by the field, you wouldn't get the order you expect.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Updated the answer to a working solution.